# Method to sort values in row in pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, vector

Consider the following `pandas.Series` object:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["hello there you would like to sort me", "sorted i would like to be", "the yankees played the red sox", "apple apple banana fruit orange cucumber"])
```

I would like to sort the values **inside** each row, similar to the following approach:

```
for row in s.index:
    split_words = s.loc[row].split()
    split_words.sort()
    s.loc[row] = " ".join(split_words)
```

I have a huge dataset, however, so vectorization is important, here. How can I use pandas `str` attribute to accomplish the same, but much quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the string accessor `str` and `split`.  Then apply `sorted` and `join`.

```
s.str.split().apply(sorted).str.join(' ')

0       hello like me sort there to would you
1                   be i like sorted to would
2              played red sox the the yankees
3    apple apple banana cucumber fruit orange
dtype: object
```

Comment: Green check mark because you used `pandas.Series.str` method as was asked in question above.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced that Python lists perform better in these situations. Applying piRSquared's logic, a list comprehension would be:

```
[' '.join(sorted(sentence.split())) for sentence in s.tolist()]
```

For timings I've used Shakespeare's works from [Peter Norvig's website](http://norvig.com/ngrams/).

```
s = pd.read_table('shakespeare.txt', squeeze=True, header=None)
s = pd.Series(s.tolist()*10)
r1 = s.str.split().apply(sorted).str.join(' ')
r2 = pd.Series([' '.join(sorted(sentence.split())) for sentence in s.tolist()])

r1.equals(r2)
Out: True

%timeit s.str.split().apply(sorted).str.join(' ')
1 loop, best of 3: 2.71 s per loop

%timeit pd.Series([' '.join(sorted(sentence.split())) for sentence in s.tolist()])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.95 s per loop
```